# Unable to define correct struct for asn decoding in golang

Tags: go, asn.1

I have the following [ASN1 structure](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAhxW%2BfVIU3KiVWyHy5RZ6jMQrXbrpUNOrz8V29qhZ98G53o6yKeUc2dOXC%2FdX2w8lEXjf%2BHys9BLAJJZc6dlV1vrVZM5C9fvCAMHlAcMW2AADLuG%2BSruM6URBedSAxMFVwAzsSApLEQSlfGyMvjT%2BUOrHEjBUMn4%2BIPiLW2G0o1pHxCkrUxub%2FRWpl5qO7BbuEQj4flbUGpOpFW%2BXOuYu78MRmEvl%2FE9SX8b04RrXZTxPMAqxAl%2FzRA7VgIVzwtcm6xjzFw8kvr7H4B%2Fzb7Jvl32FhniXMOrPfSGI2xhrr92DTOaPXuPFH2DywbNj%2FO21fenykWYsB%2FbA8vH7%2FEmQdwIDAQAB) to decode using golang

```
SEQUENCE(2 elem)
     SEQUENCE(2 elem)
          OBJECT IDENTIFIER1.2.840.113549.1.1.1
          NULL
     BIT STRING(1 elem)
          SEQUENCE(2 elem)
               INTEGER(2048 bit) 20832…
               INTEGER  65537
```

and I am using the following struct to store the decoded data:

```
type OidAndNullSET struct {
    OID  asn1.ObjectIdentifier
    Null asn1.RawValue
}

type Seq struct {
    Set    OidAndNullSET
    BitStr asn1.BitString
}

func main() {
    mdata2 := []byte("MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAhxW+fVIU3KiVWyHy5RZ6jMQrXbrpUNOrz8V29qhZ98G53o6yKeUc2dOXC/dX2w8lEXjf+Hys9BLAJJZc6dlV1vrVZM5C9fvCAMHlAcMW2AADLuG+SruM6URBedSAxMFVwAzsSApLEQSlfGyMvjT+UOrHEjBUMn4+IPiLW2G0o1pHxCkrUxub/RWpl5qO7BbuEQj4flbUGpOpFW+XOuYu78MRmEvl/E9SX8b04RrXZTxPMAqxAl/zRA7VgIVzwtcm6xjzFw8kvr7H4B/zb7Jvl32FhniXMOrPfSGI2xhrr92DTOaPXuPFH2DywbNj/O21fenykWYsB/bA8vH7/EmQdwIDAQAB")


    var n Seq
    _, err1 := asn1.Unmarshal(mdata2, &n)
    checkError(err1)

    fmt.Println("After unmarshal: ", n)
}

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Fatal error: %s", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

I cannot find a proper structure to store a SEQUENCE* and getting following error

> asn1: structure error: tags don't match (16 vs {class:1 tag:13 length:73 isCompound:false}).

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know Golang.  I guess the error is telling you it found an [APPLICATION 13] tag ?? But there is no such tag in your data.  Which leads to my next question - when you assign mdata2, is that string interpreted as base64, or are the characters converted to bytes according to, say, UTF-8?  That might be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You defined base64-encoded ASN.1 stream and need to decode it before passing to `Unmarshal`. Consider the next definition:

```
mdata2, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAhxW+fVIU3KiVWyHy5RZ6jMQrXbrpUNOrz8V29qhZ98G53o6yKeUc2dOXC/dX2w8lEXjf+Hys9BLAJJZc6dlV1vrVZM5C9fvCAMHlAcMW2AADLuG+SruM6URBedSAxMFVwAzsSApLEQSlfGyMvjT+UOrHEjBUMn4+IPiLW2G0o1pHxCkrUxub/RWpl5qO7BbuEQj4flbUGpOpFW+XOuYu78MRmEvl/E9SX8b04RrXZTxPMAqxAl/zRA7VgIVzwtcm6xjzFw8kvr7H4B/zb7Jvl32FhniXMOrPfSGI2xhrr92DTOaPXuPFH2DywbNj/O21fenykWYsB/bA8vH7/EmQdwIDAQAB")
```

Then it should work after adding `"encoding/base64"` to imports.